# Valgrind Errors

Tags: c, valgrind

I am having trouble deciphering the Valgrind output that I am getting.  For example I have an error that says I am doing an illegal write of size 1.  So I added one to the malloc and that doesn't change anything.  Since I have never used Valgrind before, I thought it would be best to get some help after searching online yielded no responses.  Please be aware that I am not looking for the answer so I have not reproduced my code.  I would like to be pushed in the correct direction so that I can combat future errors.
Thanks!

```
==28881== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28881== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28881== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28881== Command: ./sws root
==28881==
==28892== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28892==    at 0x4C286D9: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:284)
==28892==    by 0x4040B7: get_headers (html.c:280)
==28892==    by 0x402D77: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28892==    at 0x4C286D9: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:284)
==28892==    by 0x4040C5: get_headers (html.c:280)
==28892==    by 0x402D77: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28892==    at 0x4C286D9: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:284)
==28892==    by 0x4040D3: get_headers (html.c:280)
==28892==    by 0x402D77: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28892==    at 0x4C286D9: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:284)
==28892==    by 0x4040E1: get_headers (html.c:280)
==28892==    by 0x402D77: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid write of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C2874C: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:311)
==28892==    by 0x4041E1: get_headers (html.c:299)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be030 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid write of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C2875F: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:311)
==28892==    by 0x4041E1: get_headers (html.c:299)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be034 is 4 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid read of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C28374: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x4041F7: get_headers (html.c:300)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be030 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid write of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C2838C: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x4041F7: get_headers (html.c:300)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be034 is 4 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid write of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C2839F: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x4041F7: get_headers (html.c:300)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be061 is 15 bytes before a block of size 40 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x403E53: get_headers (html.c:224)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid read of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C28374: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x40420D: get_headers (html.c:301)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892== Invalid read of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C28374: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x40420D: get_headers (html.c:301)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be030 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid write of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C2838C: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x40420D: get_headers (html.c:301)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be061 is 15 bytes before a block of size 40 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x403E53: get_headers (html.c:224)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid read of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C28374: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x404223: get_headers (html.c:302)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be030 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid read of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C28374: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x404239: get_headers (html.c:303)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be030 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid write of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C2838C: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==28892==    by 0x404239: get_headers (html.c:303)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be098 is 0 bytes after a block of size 40 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x403E53: get_headers (html.c:224)
==28892==    by 0x402E00: read_page (networking.c:347)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Invalid read of size 1
==28892==    at 0x4C286E4: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:284)
==28892==    by 0x402E0F: read_page (networking.c:348)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be030 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==28892==    at 0x5121052: send (send.c:28)
==28892==    by 0x40276D: send_msg (networking.c:245)
==28892==    by 0x402E29: read_page (networking.c:348)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==  Address 0x53be030 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==28892==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==28892==    by 0x402D84: read_page (networking.c:341)
==28892==    by 0x402B8E: get_page (networking.c:310)
==28892==    by 0x40268E: header_parse (networking.c:232)
==28892==    by 0x401D96: retrieve_msg (networking.c:62)
==28892==    by 0x401AAB: main (sws.c:139)
==28892==
==28892==
==28892== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28892==     in use at exit: 337 bytes in 10 blocks
==28892==   total heap usage: 19 allocs, 9 frees, 3,307 bytes allocated
==28892==
==28892== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28892==    definitely lost: 337 bytes in 10 blocks
==28892==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28892==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28892==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28892==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28892== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==28892==
==28892== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28892== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==28892== ERROR SUMMARY: 348 errors from 17 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
==28881==
==28881== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28881==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28881==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==28881==
==28881== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28881==
==28881== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28881== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

---

```
217 int get_headers(char* time, char* last_modified, char* server, char* content_type, size_t msglen, char* header, int flag)
218 {
219         char* header1 = NULL;
220         char* header2 = NULL;
221         char* header3 = NULL;
222         char* header4 = NULL;
223         char* header5 = NULL;
224
225         if ((header1 = (char*)malloc(strlen("Date: ")+strlen(time)+2) ) ==NULL)
226         {
227                 fprintf(stderr, "%s: No more memory\n", getprogname());
228                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
229         }
230
231
232         strcpy(header1, "Date: ");
233         strcat(header1, time);
234         strcat(header1, "\n");
235
236
237         if ((header2 = (char*)malloc(strlen("Last-Modified: ")+strlen(last_modified)+5) ) ==NULL)
238         {
239                 fprintf(stderr, "%s: No more memory\n", getprogname());
240                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
241         }
242
243
244         strcpy(header2, "Last-Modified: ");
245         strcat(header2, last_modified);
246         strcat(header2, "\n");
247
248
249         if ((header3 = (char*)malloc(strlen("Server: ")+strlen(server)+5) ) ==NULL)
250         {
251                 fprintf(stderr, "%s: No more memory\n", getprogname());
252                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
253         }
254
255
256         strcpy(header3, "Server: ");
257         strcat(header3, server);
258         strcat(header3, "\n");
259
260
261         if ((header4 = (char*)malloc(strlen("Content-Type: ")+strlen(content_type)+5) ) ==NULL)
262         {
263                 fprintf(stderr, "%s: No more memory\n", getprogname());
264                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
265         }
266
267
268         strcpy(header4, "Content-Type: ");
269         strcat(header4, content_type);
270         strcat(header4, "\n");
271
272
273         int content_length = strlen(header1)+strlen(header2)+strlen(header3)+strlen(header4)+strlen("Content-Length: ")+msglen+5;
274         char temp[10] = {' '};
275         snprintf(temp, sizeof(msglen),"%d", content_length);
276
277         if ((header5 = (char*)malloc(strlen("Content-Length: ")+strlen(temp)+5) ) ==NULL)
278         {
279                 fprintf(stderr, "%s: No more memory\n", getprogname());
280                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
281         }
282
283
284         strcpy(header5, "Content-Length: ");
285         strncat(header5, temp, strlen(temp));
286         strcat(header5, "\n\n");
287
288
289         if(flag == 1)
290         {
291                 strcpy(header, header1);
292                 strcat(header, header2);
293                 strcat(header, header3);
294                 strcat(header, header4);
295                 strcat(header, header5);
296         }
297
298         return content_length;
299         free(header1);
300         free(header2);
301         free(header3);
302         free(header4);
303         free(header5);
304 }
```

Comment: Seeing the respective code locations would be helpful to explain those messages.

Comment: @BjoernD I've added the function (with relative line numbers) that problems with valgrind

Comment: Is it possible that `flag` is false? In that case you don't put any data into `header1`, `header2` etc. but you still call `strlen` with them (uninitialised).

Comment: `strcat(header1, "\0");` - this is just silly. it doesn't do anything.

Comment: and what's the point of those mallocs? you could directly write to `header`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I can't write directly to the header because I do not want to have a fixed sized buffer to store the header because I do not know the size the header will be before entering this function.

Comment: @tpar44: ?? you pass the header pointer and you write to it in this function...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I call this function twice.  Once to get the size of the header, then i Malloc the retuned size and call it again this time adding things to the header pointer

Comment: well, now it makes sense, as you updated your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `flag` is 0, then you never initialize any of the data in the `header1..4` strings, so when you try to get their lengths with `strlen`, you read in uninitialized garbage.  You should make sure to always initialize the header values to empty strings regardless of the `flag` setting.

Also, there's no need to `strcat(..., "\0")` onto the string -- `strcpy` and `strcat` always null-terminate the strings (in fact, `"\0"` is indistinguishable from the empty string `""`, since both of their first bytes are the NUL byte).  And beware of [Shlemiel the Painter algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) when concatenating a bunch of strings together.

Comment: Based on OP's `+ 5` for the malloc, I have a strong suspicion that he really meant to write `strcat(..., "\\n\\0");`.  I would use sprintf or something similar.

Comment: no, that's not what he meant. it's generating an HTTP response header

Answer (score 1):

1) You malloc'd 5 pieces of memory and did not free them in your function. These should be freed before you return or exit. Notice how valgrind is saying you have 326 bytes that were `definitely lost`.

2) If `flag` is false, your `header*` variables never get set to anything, which is why valgrind is giving you a bunch of errors on line 280. Subsequently, there's nothing good for it to copy later around line 301, so you get more errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in writing 'neat + cool' code, I am going to attempt to nudge you in the right direction. The best way to combat future errors is to keep it simple.

What is simple? Doing it in as few lines as possible, but still keeping it readable and easy to understand. Instead of 87 lines (304-217) of code, you can do it in 30 lines.

Also, it is a good mindset to lookout for places where the code could go into 'undefined' behavior. It would be good practice to include the size of the header in get_header().  If it is not available in get_header(), then there is no way to prevent potential buffer overflow/memory corruption.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
get_header(char *date, char *last_m, char *server, char *c_type,
        int c_len, char *header, int flag, int h_len);

int
main()
{
        char header[500];
        int n;

        n = get_header(
                "Fri, 09 Nov 2012 09:22:06 GMT", /* Date            */
                "Fri, 09 Nov 2012 09:10:32 GMT", /* Last modified   */
                "MySuperDuperServer/V 1.0.0.0",  /* Server name     */
                "Text/html",                     /* Content type    */
                1234,                            /* Content length  */
                header,                          /* Destination buf */
                1,             /* 1 = write into header, 0 = Do not */
                sizeof(header)                   /* header buf size */
        );             

        printf("%s\n", header);

        exit(0);
}

/* Header lines should end with CR LF */

#define DATE   "Date: %s\r\n"
#define LAST_M "Last-Modified: %s\r\n"
#define SERVER "Server : %s\r\n"
#define C_TYPE "Content-Type: %s\r\n"
#define C_LEN  "Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n"

#define HEADER DATE LAST_M SERVER C_TYPE C_LEN

int
get_header(char *date, char *last_m, char *server, char *c_type,
        int c_len, char *header, int flag, int h_len)
{
        char *d;
        int r;

        if (flag == 1) {
                d = header;
        }
        else if ((d = (char *)malloc(h_len)) == 0) {
                printf("out of memory\n");
                exit(1); /* exit(EXIT_FAILURE); */
        }

        r = snprintf(d, h_len, HEADER, date, last_m, server, c_type, c_len);

        if (flag == 0) {
                free(d);
        }

        return(r);
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.